# Optimizing intersections of sets

Tags: graph-theory, optimization

I'm having the following problem where I have this graph of 2 sets of nodes with connections between them:

[Link to Graph.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qF3dI.png)
Now I want to find the subsets which contain all the possible sets, but without the sets which are already contained in other sets.

For example, from the image:
all our possible sets (without empty ones) are:

> {(S1), (M1)}, {(S1), (M2)}, {(S1), (M1, M2)}, {(S1, S2), (M2)}, {(S2), (M2)}, {(S3), (M3)}

However I don't need all those sets, instead I can take:

> {(S1), (M1, M2)}, {(S1, S2), (M2)}, {(S3), (M3)}

without:

> {(S1), (M1)}, {(S1), (M2)}, {(S2), (M2)}

since each one of the items in this ^ sets is contained in the more "bigger" set
 (the items in the sets I don't need always intersect with the bigger sets?)

I thought about just doing power set of all the items in SET A.
Then going over each possibility of the power set, taking the items that are connected from SET B and intersect them to get the "bigger" set.

But I do have more than a hundred items in set A which mean the power set will be 2^n possibilities, which will take huge amount of time for computer to run through.

Is there better solution to this problem?

Comment: How do you determine what is a "possible set" and what isn't? I'm not clear on what the definition is.

Comment: If all the items are connected (from each set to each set) then it is a possible set

Comment: Even with that clarification, I cannot figure out what you mean. Why is $\{S1, S2, M1, M2\}$ not possible (I left off the parentheses as they appear to serve no useful purpose in your sets at all, just gathering together elements already distinguished by their labels)? As far as I can *guess* what this convoluted verbiage is saying, your minimal collection would be $\{S1, S2, M1, M2\}$ and $\{S3, M3\}$, but you've left $\{S1, S2, M1, M2\}$ out of your list of "all possible sets" without any explanation.

Comment: @PaulSinclair You can't have a set where you use S2 with M1 since they are not connected, you can however to use S1,S2 for M2 since both S1 and S2 are connected to M2.

The answer I approved does exactly what I meant.

Comment: And why would you expect anyone to know that "possible set" meant "complete bipartite subgraph"? The point of my comment is that you assumed that people would somehow "know" what you meant without your having to explain it, despite your not using any standard terminology. You are just lucky that Misha appears to be a good guesser.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I am not a mathematician so I didn't know the terminology I just encounter the problem, I hopped people understand the question from the examples (and so they did).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, some terminology: the "possible sets" are just the complete bipartite subgraphs (the bicliques) of your graph, and so your goal is to find all the maximal bicliques.

Second, some bad news: if there are $n$ nodes on either side, in general there is no way to avoid checking $2^n$ possibilities. In the bipartite cocktail party graph, if the vertices are $S_1, \dots, S_n$ on one side and $M_1, \dots, M_n$ on the other, the edges are the pairs $(S_i, M_j)$ with $i \ne j$. Then any subset of the vertices $\{S_i : i \in I\}$ on one side has its own maximal biclique with the vertices $\{M_j : j \notin I\}$ on the other side. Since you need to output $2^n$ results, you can't hope for a fast algorithm.

What you *can* hope for is an algorithm whose running time scales with the number of results - so if there are few results, the algorithm will also be relatively efficient. This is can be reduced to a well-studied problem: if we take the bipartite complement of our graph, including all pairs $(S_i, M_j)$ which are *not* edges of our graph, then bicliques turn into independent sets. Wikipedia lists [a whole bunch of citations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_independent_set#cite_note-14) for algorithms that find all maximal independent sets in a graph in polynomial time per result. I expect that all of these are kind of complicated to implement.

---

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699714/find-all-maximal-complete-bipartite-subgraph-from-given-bipartite-graph) also considers the problem of finding all maximal bicliques, but I can't entirely endorse the answer given there. The [Bron–Kerbosch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bron%E2%80%93Kerbosch_algorithm), although it's the best option for some problems, has a worst-case running time of $3^{2n/3}$ on a $2n$-vertex graph. This is *worse* than the brute force $2^n$ approach.

Also, it's not necessarily sensitive to the number of maximal bicliques. It's sensitive to the degeneracy of the graph, so it's efficient for sparse graphs. But it's an algorithm for finding maximal cliques; to reduce to that problem we need to add all edges $(S_i, S_j)$ and $(M_i, M_j)$ to our graph, and the result is never sparse.

Its one nice feature is that's easy to implement: much more so than any of the algorithms I link to above.

Comment: Just the answer I needed, I settled to Bron–Kerbosch algorithm with my own pre optimizations to get the lowest possible vertics and connections before I run the algorithm.

I use: https://github.com/SeregPie/almete.BronKerbosch
in case anyone need nodejs code implementation.